# Is there an equivalent to flashbake (easy version control) for Perforce or Subversion

Tags: svn, git, version-control, perforce

Flashbake is introduced by [Cory Doctorow](http://craphound.com/?p=2171) and discussed [here](http://bitbucketlabs.net/flashbake/) and its [project page is here](http://wiki.github.com/commandline/flashbake).  It hides most of the complexity of git and allows simple configuration.  I'm looking for something for Perforce since I have 10s of GB growing to 100+ GB in the next year of a few MB files (pictures mainly) which might not be ideal for git.  I also had trouble with > 1 GB files (video) Plus I have used Perforce and svn before.

EDITS: 10/26/09: This is only for me so there isn't a requirement for multiple users.  I can use the free version of Perforce.  Additionally since Perforce can be called by commands, just like git and subversion, I wouldn't think the proprietary software issues would be a stopper.

10/26/09: I don't have a requirement of work disconnected, so the DVCS features of git aren't important.

10/26/09: clarified size of repository.
2/5/10: Added reference to video files

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is something for Perforce, though it is unlikely since Perforce is a commercial product.  It'd probably be reasonably straightforward to port flashbake to svn.

However, one nice thing about git (or other DVCS) is that no remote server is needed and you can "flashbake" at any time, even on an airplane.  (Of course you could have your svn or p4d repository local too.)  Git also makes it very easy to clone your repository and share it.

If you are worried about git and binary performance, you may want to read:

- [SO: Git or Subversion for binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126239/git-or-subversion-for-binary-files)
- the middle para of [this blog post](http://grumbel.blogspot.com/2008/04/why-git-rocks.html) about binary file deltas during clone.